# Carthage error: No available version for binary

Tags: ios, swift, continuous-integration, carthage

When specifying a new version of a binary in a Cartfile. 
Carthage is unable to download/find a new version returning an error.

eg:

`binary "<URL>" == 1.1.0` (was previously `binary "<URL>" == 1.0.0`)

error:

`No available version for binary "<URL>" satisfies the requirement: == 1.1.0`

Answer (score 9):

This can be resolved by removing the cache for Carthage in the following places:

`rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/`

`rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/carthage/`